# Limit bandwidth SFTP user

Tags: sftp, bandwidth

Is there any possibility to limit the bandwidth of an SFTP user? My server has an upload of ~500kb/s and I don't want to 'spend' it all on one user

Comment: possibly you coukld use `tc`, but that doesn't understand "users", only ip addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using WHM (Web Host Manager), you can simply go to "Limit Bandwidth Usage" under the "Account Functions" section. Choose an account and then enter a limit.

If not, you can use a utility called trickle - https://github.com/mariusae/trickle

Comment: Accepted answer is getting downvotes. Completely irrelevant but otherwise accurate references to man pages is getting upvotes. Weird!

Answer (score 12):

For openssh, see [man sftp](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/sftp.1.html)

> ```
>  -l limit
>         Limits the used bandwidth, specified in Kbit/s.
> ```

Comment: Alright, this enables someone who logs in to the shell to limit his own bandwidth. However, I want to limit the user's bandwidth before the log in, permanently. I don't think you can do that with the -l parameter.

Comment: OpenSSH doesn't support a server side bandwith limit.